# Bucle with plotly

Tags: python

I have a dataframe and I can to build a chart with this code

```
py.sign_in(username='XXXXXXX', api_key='XXXXXXXX')
py.iplot( c, filename = 'candlestick-test-3', validate = False )
```

But now, I have a list of dataframe and I want to build n charts for these dataframe using this code..

```
def ch (datachart):
    for c in datachart:
        py.sign_in(username='Ppuertas1978', api_key='9K5pkCtq5yp8zlv4M6gc')
        py.iplot( c, filename = 'candlestick-test-3', validate = False )

ch(datachart)
```

But when I execute this code, the output is...

> c:\pp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\display.py:689: UserWarning:
>
> Consider using IPython.display.IFrame instead

And I haven't the C charts...

Comment: You might want to redact your username and API key.

The output is just a warning. Did the charts show up?

Comment: ok, I have the solution. I have to paid to add new charts